# git, Rails, and cache in public/ directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, caching, branch, public

I'm working on a Rails app using git for version control, and I'm running into an issue with generated cache files that are put in the `public/` directory. Some of the (static) files in `public/` should be version controlled, but generated cache files should not. I originally approached this by git-ignoring those files, which seems to mostly work correctly. However, when switching branches, `git checkout` gives an error message during the change because of the unexpected cache files not under version control (it seems).

What's the right way to approach managing cache files in the `public/` directory using git?

Comment: I think .gitignore doesn't allow files to pass a checkout once it's seen them even if you put them in the gitignore. Maybe a hard reset, and then the ones still left in the gitignore will be actually ignored? just a guess..

Comment: What error message is git giving? what does your .gitignore file look like?

Comment: @Peter: Hmm, after trying again I don't see the error I saw before. Maybe something else was wrong when I did it before.